# Django mutli-threading on apache/mod_wsgi/windows

Tags: apache-2.2, django, windows, mod-wsgi, multi-threading

I am quite new to the combination of apache and django and quite naive frankly regarding to how multi-threading is handeled. Specifically I run on a windows server, so I know the MPM is only thread-based.

I have an application which serves a website's pages, and another application which performs a cpu intensive background process which happens from time to time and takes as much as 30 seconds or so.
I am worried that I might run into performance issues and have several questions, I hope these will help others as well...

1. How does apache distribute concurrent requests between threads? and between CPUs? What kind of logic drives this? Does each request spawn a separate thread?
2. Can I manually specify a certain app to be run on a separate CPU? For example, if I have a machine with 4 CPUs, can I set 1 CPU for website requests and 3 other for running the background process on demand?
3. How do multiple threads read/write to same database? I don't expect to have collisions since writing will be carried out per-user, but I don't know how this is actually handeled.
4. What happens if I have more than one such machine, for example running on EC2 and having more than one instance? How are requests distributed?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

For general reading see:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ProcessesAndThreading
- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/03/python-interpreter-is-not-created-for.html

**How does apache distribute concurrent requests between threads?**

For a multithreaded configuration there is a pool of pre created threads. When a new request arrives, that gets handed off to one of the available threads in the pool to process. When done the thread goes back into the pool.

**How does apache distribute concurrent requests between CPUs?**

It doesn't, where a thread runs at any specific point in time is determined by the operating system. Threads are not bound to a specific processor by Apache, so execution can move around.

**Does each request spawn a separate thread?**

For web requests handled by Apache the answer is no.

**Can I manually specify a certain app to be run on a separate CPU?**

There are ways that you can set processor affinity to bind processes to processors, but how you do that is system dependent. Apache itself doesn't as far as I know provide any configuration mechanism for doing that to itself.

**How do multiple threads read/write to same database?**

Carefully. Usually the database server process worries about all that and so you don't have to worry. In a client, you do need to make sure though that each thread is using its own database connection, by creating one for each request, or you have a pool of database connections and threads grab a connection from the pool when required and return it when done.

Note that this presumes a database where access is mediated via a server process. If you are using a file system based database, then the database client library should ensure multithread access is safe.

**What happens if I have more than one such machine, for example running on EC2 and having more than one instance? How are requests distributed?**

You would need some sort of front end load balancer to distribute requests. That may be a proper load balancer, or you might use a nginx front end as proxy.